# riscv: qemu scall versus spike ecall

Tags: system-calls, qemu, riscv

My understanding is that `scall` and `ecall` are the same in `riscv`. However, `qemu` `riscv` `scall` implementation is different from spike `ecall` implementation. Would you please explain me the difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

QEMU is currently out of date for RISC-V's newest privilege spec. When in doubt, assume spike is correct.